# How to fix step size and number of steps in the scipy integrator 'dopri5'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I have written code in python to solve differential equations using scipy integrator `dopri5`. Frequently I am getting an error unsuccessful integration. Then I tried to change number of steps but again I am getting the error that step size become too small. When I am setting `nsteps=1` then error showing that more step should be needed. 
I don't know where I am wrong? And how to fix this problem?

```
Warning (from warnings module):
self.messages.get(istate, unexpected_istate_msg)))
UserWarning: dopri5: step size becomes too small
state = ODE.integrate(0.0001)
File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jitcode/_jitcode.py", line 644, in integrate
 return self.integrator.integrate(*args,**kwargs)
 packages/jitcode/integrator_tools.py", line 143, in integrate
    raise UnsuccessfulIntegration
jitcode.integrator_tools.UnsuccessfulIntegration
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: We'll have to see your code to give any kind of meaningful answer.